# How to get value from checkbox list in October CMS custom plugin

Tags: templates, twig, octobercms

I entered project_toolbox into my plugin's database table and created checkbox list named project_toolbox with 10 values. How can I retrieve those value if checked from the backend.

Here is what I was unable to get the value of the checkbox value

```
<div class="project-toolbox">
{% for toolbox in project.project_toolbox %}
    <div class="{{ option.name }}"><span>{{ toolbox.name }} Hello</span></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share output of `{{ dump(project.project_toolbox) }}` so we can share you how to use them

Comment: The result is string string string...something I wrote is wrong?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the multiple string text https://ibb.co/kJPyZBG. Does these dump result mean that I code it wrong? It show that the checkbox I have checked show but only showing the text "String".

Comment: it seems screenshot is not accessible can you please add it to question

Comment: I have uploaded the image to the original post

Comment: I assume these 8 values you have checked correct `0-7` -> `total 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through array

```
<div class="project-toolbox">
{% for toolbox_item in project.project_toolbox %}
    <div class="{{ option.name }}"><span>{{ toolbox_item }} Hello</span></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

> You can directly use string value `{{ toolbox_item }}` as `project_toolbox` is the array of strings.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: your most welcome 

Comment: Trying to tidy up the the appearance of the data, how can I display the value instead key?

Comment: you can use `{% for key,value in array %}` to get key and value